# MySQL select average prices of a product for the 5 latest dates

Tags: mysql, date, average, price

I have a product table with the following columns:(price,productname,date). How I do I find the average prices of productnames that have "JACKET" in it for the 5 latest dates found in the table?

I want to extract the 5 average prices and the 5 dates.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
SELECT avg(price) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE PRODUCT like "%JACKET%" 
    ORDER BY orderdate DESC Limit 0, 5 )
```

Comment: I don't believe this solves his question, 1. He said WHERE productname contains the word "JACKET" and 2. he wants columns, price, productname and date.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the query posted previously, with a few small changes:

```
Select date, price, avg(price) from TABLE WHERE productname like '%Jacket%
order by date desc LIMIT 5
```